# NSAttributed String RTL for Arabic Language in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to show htmltext in a UILabel using NSAttributed String and one of the extension to get the linespacing, fontsize etc of it. 
But the Language of the html is RTL (Arabic).

I want to show it from Right to Left, as you can see the fullstop and colon are in wrong direction.
Also I want to remove extra spaces showing in between the heading and paragraph.

This is my Html , line of code and extension which I am using.

```
let html = newsContent!.PublishingPageContent
                let stringHtml = html!.replacingOccurrences(of:"<br>", with:"")
                lblNews.attributedText = stringHtml.htmlAttributed(family: "GEDinarOne-Medium", size: 0, color: Color.black)
                lblNews.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
                lblNews.textAlignment = .right

extension String {
    func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
                "html *" +
                "{" +
                "font-size: \(self)pt !important;" +
                "color: #\(color.colorFromHexString("000000")) !important;" +
                "font-family: \(family ?? "GEDinarOne"), GEDinarOne !important;" +
            "}</style> \(self)"

            guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }

            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

[image]

**الموعد :** تقام الفعاليات خلال الايام 5-7 يونيو
**المكان :** **(الرياض)** _ البانوراما مول
**(جدة)**  _ الردسي مول **(الخبر)** _ الراشد مول **(الجوف)** _ الجوف بلازا
**ساعات المناسبة :** 
من الساعة (9) مساءً ولغاية (1) صباحاً
**الجمهور المستهدف :**تستهدف وزارة البيئة والمياه والزراعة أفراد المجتمع من مواطنين ومقيمين وتركز في إيصال رسائل يوم البيئة العالمي على الاسرة لكونها الركيزة الأساسية للمجتمعات وهي الوحدة الاجتماعية التي تتعايش مع البيئة وتأثر بها وتتأثر بما يعتريها من سوء واهمال او تخريب وعدم مبالاة. 
نسعى من خلال التوجه لتنفيذ الفعاليات في الأسواق وخلال شهر رمضان المبارك والذي يصادف 5 يونيو الموافق 21 رمضان للوصول للأسرة وايصال اهداف ورسائل يوم البيئة العالمي والذي يقام تحت عنوان  " التغلب على التلوث البلاستيكي" , وتحمل المناسبة عنوان (سنعمل معاً من أجل بيئة أفضل) .  
**ما هو يوم البيئة العالمي؟**
يعد يوم البيئة العالمي آلية أساسية للأمم المتحدة لتشجيع الوعي العالمي والعمل من أجل البيئة , ولم ينفك هذا اليوم في التنامي مع مرور الأعوام ليصبح منبرًا عالميًا للتوعية العامة تحتفل به الأطراف المعنية في أكثر من 100 دولة على نطاق واسع, كما أنه بمثابة يوم للاحتفال بالأشخاص الذين يقومون بعمل إيجابي نحو البيئة، ويشحذ الأعمال الفردية لتكوين قوى جماعية تولد أثرًا إيجابيًا مطردًا على الكوكب , ويدور موضوع يوم البيئة العالمي هذا العام حول البلاستيك تحت عنوان « التغلب على التلوث البلاستيكي» . 
**رسالة يوم البيئة العالمي ؟**
التغلب على التلوث البلاستيكي" هو موضوع يوم البيئة العالمي لعام 2018، وهو دعوة للعمل من جانبنا جميعا لكي نتحد معا لمواجهة أحد التحديات البيئية العظيمة في عصرنا, إن موضوع يوم البيئة العالمي لعام 2018 الذي اختارته الهند البلد المضيف ليوم البيئة العالمي لهذا العام، يدعونا جميعا إلى النظر في الكيفية التي يمكننا بها إحداث تغييرات في حياتنا اليومية للحد من العبء الثقيل للتلوث البلاستيكي على أماكننا الطبيعية وحياتنا البرية وصحتنا. وفي حين أن البلاستيك له العديد من الاستخدامات القيمة، فقد أصبحنا نعتمد بصورة أكبر على البلاستيك الذي يستخدم لمرة واحدة أو غير القابل للاستعمال مرة أخرى- وما يترتب على ذلك من عواقب بيئية شديدة , وفي جميع أنحاء العالم، يتم شراء مليون زجاجة مياه شرب بلاستيكية كل دقيقة واحدة. ويتم استخدام 500 مليار كيس من أكياس البلاستيك غير القابلة للاستعمال مرة أخرى في جميع أنحاء العالم كل عام. وبصورة إجمالية، يعد 50 في المائة من البلاستيك الذي نستخدمه هو بلاستيك يستخدم لمرة واحدة. ويفتقر ما يقرب من ثلث العبوات البلاستيكية التي نستخدمها إلى أنظمة لجمعها، مما يؤدي إلى امتلاء شوارع المدينة بالمواد البلاستيكية وتلوث بيئتنا الطبيعية. وينتهي المطاف بنحو 13 مليون طن من المواد البلاستيكية في محيطاتنا، حيث تؤثر هذه المواد على الشعاب المرجانية وتهدد الحياة البرية البحرية الضعيفة. ويمكن للبلاستيك الذي نلقيه كنفايات في المحيطات أن يعادل الدوران حول الأرض أربع مرات في السنة الواحدة ، ويمكن أن يستمر في المياه لمدة تصل إلى 1000 سنة قبل أن يتحلل تماما. كما يتحلل البلاستيك ويذوب في المياه التي نشربها – وبالتالي يمكن أن يدخل في أجسادنا. فما الضرر الذي يسببه ذلك؟ لا يزال العلماء غير متأكدين من هذه المسألة، ولكن البلاستيك يحتوي على عدد من المواد الكيميائية، يعد كثير منها سام أو يؤثر على الهرمونات,  ويمكن أن يعمل البلاستيك أيضا كمغناطيس يجذب الملوثات الأخرى، بما في ذلك الديوكسينات والمعادن والمبيدات. يتيح يوم البيئة العالمي لهذا العام فرصة لكل واحد منا لاختيار العديد من الطرق التي يمكن من خلالها أن نساعد في التغلب على التلوث البلاستيكي في جميع أنحاء العالم. ومن ثم لا ينبغي علينا الانتظار حتى يوم 5 يونيو (وهو يوم البيئة العالمي) لاتخاذ إجراء حيال ذلك. هناك العديد من الأشياء التي يمكننا القيام بها حيال تلك المسألة – بدءا من مطالبة المطاعم التي تتردد عليها بأن تكف عن استخدام القش البلاستيكي (الشفاطات البلاستيكية)، عليك إحضار كوب القهوة الخاص بك واستخدامه في محل عملك بدلا من شراء قهوة في كوب بلاستيك، الضغط على المسؤولين في بلديتك لوضع خطط لإيداع الحاويات. 
**بعض الأفكار للتغلب على التلوث البلاستيكي :**
1- أحضر حقائب التسوق الخاصة بك إلى السوبر ماركت.2- اضغط على موردين الغذاء لاستخدام تغليف بدون بلاستيك.3- ارفض استعمال أدوات المائدة البلاستيكية.4- قم بالتقاط أي مواد بلاستيكية تراها في المرة القادمة التي تذهب للتنزه على الشاطئ أو الصحراء .5- ماذا يمكننا أن نقوم به لمعالجة هذه المشكلة؟ تبادل الأفكار الخاصة بك على مواقع التواصل الاجتماعي باستخدام الهاشتاق #التغلب_على_التلوث_البلاستيكي

### وللمشاركة والتطوع في خدمة البيئة الرجاء التسجيل بالضغط على الرابط التالي : (اضغط هنا)

## لمشاهدة الفيديو العالمي الخاص بالمناسبة : (أضغط هنا)

"

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462936/how-to-align-right-justify-uilabel

Comment: The text is right Aligned, but the issue is Right to Left .

Comment: I think this answer will helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632978/2991942

Answer (score 0):

Add **NSMutableParagraphStyle** with baseWritingDirection = .natural to your **NSMutableAttributedString**

```
 let attrStr = try! NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: htmlText.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

 let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .natural
        
 attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
```