# Cannot localize my Swift 5 framework. Localization import does nothing

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, internationalization

I develop a Swift 5 **framework** that runs on iOS 12 and above for iPhone and iPad.

I added French localization in addition to English, but the project info tab shows there's no localized files for both languages as shown on the image below:

[image]

When I run Xcode Editor|Export for localization I get the bundled files (including the fr.xliff file). I’ve edited fr.xliff with Xcode to translate some strings, and imported it back. But nothing changed in the app.

Btw, I can’t see any of the *.strings files in the project files hierarchy, which sounds weird.

**[Update]**

So I manually added Localizable.Strings file, and added English and French.

1. When I import xliff files, the Localizable.strings files remains empty. No apparent issue pops up.
2. When I put the `key=value` list in the string file, the NSLocalizedString() does not return the right localised version of the string (it always return the key).

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what's wrong: I had to use the full (extended) version of NSLocalizedString()  in order to make the function call get the translation from my framework `Localizable.strings` files (rather than the client application), as follows:

```
NSLocalizedString("Continue", tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, comment: "Continue in the button title of UIAladdinOnboardingViewController")
```

Where:

- `tableName`: a let global that hold the name of my localisable string file (in my case `"Aladdin.Localizable"`). I did this to avoid potential collision of .strings files (as my framework name is `Aladdin`);
- `bundle`: a let global in my the framework name space to designates the framework model bundle to pick the string from. I defined it like this: `let bundle = Bundle(for: ExtendedAppDelegate.self)` where ExtendedAppDelegate is one of my framework custom class.

**Side note of importance:**

Btw, don’t put your interpolating string as the key parameter of the `NSLocalizedString` call, otherwise it’s gonna be interpolated at runtime, leading to an interpolated string that won't exist in your string file.

Don’t do that:

```
let s = NSLocalizedString("{Start your \(introductoryPeriod) free trial.}", tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, comment: "in price display")
```

Do this:

```
let s = String(format: NSLocalizedString("{Start your %@ free trial.}", tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, comment: "{Start your \\(introductoryPeriod) free trial.}"), introductoryPeriod)
```

**With the corresponding Aladdin.Localizable.strings (en):**

```
/* {Start your \(introductoryPeriod) free trial.} (in price display) */
"{Start your %@ free trial.}" = "{Start your %@ free trial.}";
```

**To generate the strings:**

I used the gestrings from the terminal as follows:

```
 $genstrings -o en.lproj/ *.swift

 $genstrings -o fr.lproj/ *.swift
```

And so on for every target languages you have. 
Finally, do the translation straight in the string files.

Comment: Actually, instead of `String(format: NSLocalizedString(...), ...)` you typically want to use `String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(...), ... )`.
[localizedStringWithFormat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1414192-localizedstringwithformat) takes into account the current locale for number formatting, and also [handles format strings with mixed language direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569952/3727099).

Comment: Good to know this addition.