# NSLayoutManager returns incorrect character index when tapping on LTR text in RTL attributed text

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel, nslayoutmanager

I wrote code to detect if the user taps within a specific range in `UILabel`. It seems to be working in most cases, but I have noticed that tapping the last line of an attributed text creates inconsistent results.

```
public static bool DidTapRange(this UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer, UILabel label, NSRange range)
{
    using (var ts = new NSTextStorage())
    {
        var lm = new NSLayoutManager();
        var tc = new NSTextContainer(new CGSize(label.Frame.Width, double.MaxValue));

        lm.AddTextContainer(tc);
        ts.Append(label.AttributedText);
        ts.AddLayoutManager(lm);

        tc.LineFragmentPadding = (float) 0.0;
        tc.LineBreakMode = label.LineBreakMode;
        tc.MaximumNumberOfLines = (uint) label.Lines;
        tc.Size = label.Bounds.Size;

        var index = lm.GetCharacterIndex(recognizer.LocationOfTouch(0, label), tc); 
        return (nint)index >= range.Location && (nint)index < range.Location + range.Length;
     }
}
```

I'm particularly having issues with RTL text and when LTR text is mixed with it. For example, if I append LTR text to the end of RTL text and tap on it (in the below case `TapMe`), the above code returns an incorrect character index and returns false for the range check.

> عندما يريد العالم أن ‪يتكلّم ‬ ، فهو يتحدّث بلغة يونيكود. تسجّل الآن
>   لحضور المؤتمر الدولي العاشر ليونيكود (Unicode Conference)، الذي سيعقد
>   في 10-12 آذار 1997 بمدينة مَايِنْتْس، ألمانيا. و سيجمع المؤتمر بين
>   خبراء من كافة قطاعات الصناعة على الشبكة العالمية انترنيت ويونيكود، حيث
>   ستتم، على الصعيدين الدولي والمحلي على حد سواء مناقشة سبل استخدام
>   يونكود في النظم القائمة وفيما يخص التطبيقات الحاسوبية، الخطوط، تصميم
>   النصوص والحوسبة متعددة اللغات...TapMe

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Does it work in pure RTL or LTR string ?  It seems a issue of localization in iOS .You would better share a sample so that  I can test it on my side .

Comment: Here's the reproduction: https://github.com/meshport432/ioslabel If you tap on the start and end of each line, the character index will be correct, but if you tap on the last line, it will be incorrect. Note that the last line has a lot of whitespace, which may cause the issue.

Comment: I've been using this code in DEV for months but only with LTR string and I never saw the issue until I started testing RTL. This is preventing me from pushing everything to production :(

Comment: It seems a issue of localization .You could post it to github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues .

Comment: So do you think this is a Xamarin Forms issue or Xamarin.iOS issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209741/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-user246392).

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366330/in-xcode-how-to-display-text-merging-englisharabic-and-beginning-with-arabic)?

Comment: I don't believe there is anything wrong with the way RTL + LTR text is displayed. The above quote looks different on SO than iOS. On iOS, text is displayed in the same way as https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tutorial/summaries/arabic.