# Xamarin Forms: Editor acts weird on iOS when RTL text is pasted in comparison to Label

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uitextview

In Xamarin Forms, I created an `Editor` and a `Label` to test how RTL text appears in both. If I copy RTL text and paste it in the `Editor`, it looks weird whereas the `Label` looks right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20,60" Spacing="20" BackgroundColor="Beige">
        <Editor x:Name="Editor" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Completed="Editor_OnCompleted"/>

        <Label x:Name="Label" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Editor_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label.Text = Editor.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The text that is copied is on https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tutorial/summaries/arabic under sample(arabic).

This is the output:

[image]

When I use Twitter on iOS, `UITextView` and `UILabel` behave the same. How can I change the behavior of `Editor` so that the text that gets pasted appears the same as the text in `Label`? I like how Twitter handles this better. Also, on Android I don't have this problem.

Comment: Define weird for non-arabic speaking folks here. Is the text in Editor not RightToLeft or just the font is not same?

Comment: Weird in the sense that the words are out of place in comparison to the `Label`. For example, look at `عندما`. It's the first word in the `Label`, but it's the sixth word in the `Editor` (reading from right to left). I want the text to appear in the same order as the `Label`. If I paste the same text in Twitter's iOS app when composing a post, the same word appears as the first word.

Comment: It seems you havent set FlowDirection exlicitly

Comment: Is this happens only on arabic language?

Comment: Copy-paste works when I use Hebrew (except for the placement of the period sign).

Comment: I think you can open an issue in Xamarin.forms Github for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested and this issue only happens in a Xamarin.forms project. It works well in Xamarin.iOS project.

There is a workaround we found that you can use [Native Views in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml) to load those text.

While there is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml#referring-to-native-views-from-code) that it's **not possible** to name a native view with the `x:Name` attribute, it is possible to retrieve a native view instance declared in a XAML file from its code-behind file in a [Shared Access Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows).

So if you wants to do anything in code with the native `UITextView`, you would have to move to a Shared Asset project instead of using a .NET Standard project for the shared code. This may or may not be a workable solution for you.

BTW, an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10186) has been raised in Github and you can follow this to get the latest information.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, moving to a shared project is not an option for me. I'm concerned that this bug won't be fixed anytime soon. Thank you for the follow up. I opened another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688083/nslayoutmanager-returns-incorrect-character-index-when-tapping-on-ltr-text-in-rt Can you please take a look at it? Note that the text in that question is being rendered in a custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the text says but explicitly set the `FlowDirection` in each element.

I would just add it and check

```xml
<Editor x:Name="Editor" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
        Completed="Editor_OnCompleted"/>

<Label x:Name="Label" 
       FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
```

Comment: I set the `FlowDirection` to RTL for both controls. Unfortunately, the issue still persists. While the text direction changes, the words are still in different positions.

Comment: If you type manually in Editor is it as expected? If RTL on Editor is fine, then you would have to write your own Renderer.

Comment: Yes. Typing word by word seems to be working as expected. The issue only happens with copy/paste. What is a custom renderer supposed to do in this case if I wrote one?